# How can I dispose form?

Tags: c#, winforms, dispose

I am using two forms on windows application.For example `Form1()` and `Form2()` and I am working on **32 bit architecture on visual studio** . Form1 and form2 includes approximately 50mb data.

When I closed form1() and then open form2() my expectation is 50mb data from form1 will remove from ram automatically.But it doesn't work like that. When I opened form2 task manager shows me approximately 100mb  and when I come back stack is still increasing until the exception of systemoutofmemory. I don't understand why garbage collector or form dispose method do not clear the data from stack ?

I tried form dispose method and garbage collector to clear data from ram .Nevertheless both are useless for me .

some code block here after I finished my job

I will open form2

```
Form2 frm2=new Form2();

this.hide();

frm2.opendialog();
```

I expected 50mb memory for running program however the result was 100mb garbage collector or dispose method had not worked.

Comment: `this.dispose();`? You mean `frm2.ShowDialog(); frm2.Dispose();`. If you dispose of `this`, your `Form1`, what happens? Anyway, if you have created disposable objects in Form2, you need to dispose of those objects first.

Comment: this mean form1 actually this code block works on form1

Comment: "garbage collector or form dispose method do not clear the data from stack" - Neither the garbage collector or calling `Form.Dispose()` have any effect on data in the stack. They clean up heap and unmanaged memory.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve] to show us what you're doing.

Comment: the garbage collection does not work like that, in fact it does not works well at all but thats another discusion. Its not because you dispose your form that you memory is instantly release again. The GC will only kick in when there is a need, like almost running out of memory